# swift 4 AXValueGetValue optional value is nil but debugger shows a value

Tags: swift, macos

How do I get the values out of this pointer? [AXValueGetValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1462933-axvaluegetvalue?changes=latest_beta&language=objc) copies a CGRect object into my pointer. The debugger shows the pointer references an object with the values I want but fails to cast to expected CGRect type. Is this a Tuple? If so how do I get the Tuple value out of this pointer?

[image: Debugger shows code in questions and output]

Comment: @matt thanks for the tip. I found a solution which is not to use generics and construct new instances of the type I want and pass the address of the newly created type into the AXValueGetValue inout param. I am dismayed that the debugger does not hold the right snapshot of the breakpoint - memory should be captured by the closure and the code is stopped before the closure is done.

Comment: You should give your own answer to your question! Perfectly legal on Stack overflow, and might help someone else.

Comment: @matt done - posted answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround: I removed the generic function `copyAXValue<T>` and instantiated a specific inout variable directly rather than allocating one from `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`.

```
class AXValueGetters {

    class func asCGRect(value: AXValue) -> CGRect {
        var val = CGRect.zero
        AXValueGetValue(value, AXValueType.cgRect, &val)
        return val
    }

    class func asCGPoint(value: AXValue) -> CGPoint {
        var val = CGPoint.zero
        AXValueGetValue(value, AXValueType.cgPoint, &val)
        return val
    }

    class func asCFRange(value: AXValue) -> CFRange {
        var val = CFRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        AXValueGetValue(value, AXValueType.cfRange, &val)
        return val
    }

    class func asCGSize(value: AXValue) -> CGSize {
        var val = CGSize.zero
        AXValueGetValue(value, AXValueType.cgSize, &val)
        return val
    }

}
```

Comment: "感谢你,doug,你的这段代码,给我带来了很大的帮助,我一直不知道指针需要初始化空间.".翻译为英文

Comment: hey,Doug,I think we can do this too, because range maybe is nil:
var range: NSRange? = NSRange()
        if !AXValueGetValue(valRef, .cfRange, &range){
            range = nil
        }